# ASIHTTPRequest vs AFNetworking vs NSUrlRequest

Tags: iphone, ios, afnetworking

In the past I have use `ASIHTTPRequest` but now there is `NSURLRequest`.  Should we be using the `NSURLRequest` now? Are there any disadvantages?

For people reading this now: I ended up using `AFNetworking` as mentioned in the answers

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Thanks,

Comment: Don't understand the downvote...

Comment: ASIHTTPNetworking is no longer supported and shouldn't be used (IIRC). I tend to roll my own networking using NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection etc...

Comment: I dont get blocks in NSURL*  so i use afnetworking plus its uiimageview category is sugar to use..ASIHTTP gave problems in iPod1+iOS6 Combinations simply didnt work

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`NSURLConnection` and `NSURLRequest` are the provided Cocoa classes for managing connections. In iOS 7, Apple added `NSURLSession`.

But I think you'll find [`AFNetworking`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) to be a framework that further simplifies network requests (notably complex HTTP requests). If you don't want to use third-party frameworks for any reason, you can use `NSURLConnection` and/or `NSURLSession` directly. It just takes a little more coding.

If you're looking for a good `ASIHTTPRequest` alternative, `AFNetworking` is a great candidate.

For information on `NSURLConnection` and `NSURLSession` see the [URL Loading System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html).

Answer (score 20):

`NSURLRequest` has been there since iOS2.0 (see the [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html)), so it is not precisely new. `ASIHTTPRequest` has been discontinued, the [last update](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) was on 15th May 2011, so you shouldn't use it. *AFNetworking is a delightful networking library for iOS and Mac OS X* as described by them [self](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), and really makes your live easier, in my case it is the first framework I include in my network required projects.

Which one you should use?, I think this depends on your requirements, with `NSURLRequest` and `NSURLConnection` you can do everything, in fact AFNetworking *us built on top of NSURLConnection*. But how I tell you before, AFNetworking has my upvote.

**EDIT post iOS7**

If you are targeting iOS7 you should take a look to NSURLSession, check the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/Introduction/Introduction.html), and this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial).

**EDIT for Swift**

Take a look to the [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) project for an implementation done in Swift, it is also created by mattt (the main author of AFNetworking).

Comment: For Switch or for Swift?? Also, why should I choose to use Alamofire over existing libraries? Do I really care that it's written in Swift?!

Comment: @AlexSmith thanks for the correction, fixed ;-). Sorry for the delay but I was totally offline

Comment: But `ASIHTTPRequest` has bandwidth-throttling-support, unlike the other two?

Answer (score 7):

The asihttprequest is outdated library that doesn't support now for development. Do not use it.

the NSURLRequest is default iOS (cocoa) class to use. I recommend it for very little usage because you will need to write lots of code to handle connection responses.
On top of it are build all http libraries.

The AFNetwoking is standart now for http, imho. It uses blocks for callbacks, it supports different types of data json, xml etc. it is well designed and can be easily subclassed. it is best.

Answer (score 1):

> **Native (NSURLSession) vs AFNetworking or any other library.**

I would recommend you to use NSURLSession because it gives you a lot of customization on app end. Recently I was working on a project, I have to use **multipart form data** some where in the app. I have to provide my request body to the backend guy, I did use AfNetworking logger to print my body but it did not help me. so I did move to cocoa native library and got my solution.

so I would suggest you to use iOS native networking because it gives you a lot of customization but if you would need less code then you can use any 3rd party library.