# What are the difference among NSURLConnection, NSURLSession and AFNetworking?

Tags: ios

I want to know that what are the basic differences among them and what is the best and common method for managing webservices in iOS end in Objective-c and swift.

As previously I worked in Objective-c and when we need to use webservices we are using AFNetworking and NSURLConnections, As NSURLSession launches I moved to work with this one in swift.
So which one is suitable, so I can able to manage all webservices network connections conditions etc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Difference among `NSURLConnection`, `NSURLSession`**

> The entire model is different. `NSURLSession` is designed around the
>   assumption that you'll have a lot of requests that need similar
>   configuration (standard sets of headers, etc.), and makes life much
>   easier if you do.
>
> `NSURLSession` also provides support for background downloads, which
>   make it possible to continue downloading resources while your app
>   isn't running (or when it is in the background on iOS). For some use
>   cases, this is also a major win.
>
> `NSURLSession` also provide a grouping of related requests, making it
>   easy to cancel all of the requests associated with a particular work
>   unit, such as canceling all loads associated with loading a web page
>   when the user closes the window or tab.
>
> `NSURLSession` also provides nicer interfaces for requesting data
>   using blocks, in that it allows you to combine them with delegate
>   methods for doing custom authentication handling, redirect handling,
>   etc., whereas with `NSURLConnection` if you suddenly realized you
>   needed to do those things, you had to refactor your code to not use
>   block-based callbacks.

**Difference among `NSURLConnection`, `NSURLSession` and AFNetworking?**

> `NSURLConnection` and `NSURLRequest` are the provided Cocoa classes
>   for managing connections. In iOS 7, Apple added NSURLSession.
>
> But I think you'll find [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) to be a framework that
>   further simplifies network requests (notably complex HTTP requests).
>   If you don't want to use third-party frameworks for any reason, you
>   can use `NSURLConnection` and/or `NSURLSession` directly. It just
>   takes a little more coding.
>
> For information on `NSURLConnection` and `NSURLSession` see the [URL
>   Loading System Programming Guide.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html)
>
> Find from [reference1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718998/asihttprequest-vs-afnetworking-vs-nsurlrequest) and [reference2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28105504/what-is-the-biggest-difference-between-nsurlconnection-and-nsurlsession)

Thank [rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1271826/rob) and [dgatwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1564391/dgatwood) for such an amazing Answer...

Comment: Thanks for providing references.....