# which is easy to use Afnetworking/Nsurlsession/Alamofire

Tags: ios, rest, api, afnetworking, nsurlsession

I want to make rest api call. I m confused to use Afnetworking or NSurlsession or alamofire with SWIFT 3.0. Can anyone suggest me to use which one.

Comment: does not a problem choice is urs, use NSURLSession or alamofire, but alamofire or afnetworking are also using same NSUrlsession, only one advantage is code is optimized and reusability

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSURLSession` is newer than `NSURLConnection`, if you are using swift language then you can use your own custom methods by using `NSURLSession` or you can use Alamofire.

The `NSURLConnection` used in AFNetworking frameworks, If you are using objective - c then you can use it, that means not that you cannot use `NSURLSession`.

`NSURLSession` launch after iOS 7.0 or 8.0. It is more efficient that `NSURLConnection`.

At last,
If you want to make your own custom API framework then you can use `NSURLSession`(for swift)(I also used this).

If you don't required the custom framework then use Alamofire Framework.

For more details you can refer this link:

[What are the difference among NSURLConnection, NSURLSession and AFNetworking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40542118/what-are-the-difference-among-nsurlconnection-nsurlsession-and-afnetworking)

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 3.0 Alamofire is best because it is well Optimized and also reusable and it has also many Build in features.

If You are using Objective- C then you can use AFNetworking.

AFNetworking and Alamofire are from same Developers but in Different Languages.